# Can entity tracking be turned off?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got multiple entities set up with their respective repositories, all working properly. However, Doctrine seems to populate proxies where I don't want them to be populated.

I've got an entity called Item, which references a Category, both by having a `$category_id` and a `$category` field. The latter has the relationship set up with `@ORM\ManyToOne()` and `@ORM\JoinColumn()`, working correctly.

In my controller, when I'm querying Items, I receive a list of items with proxies to the related categories, which I can strip out from my response, identifying them as being proxies. However, if for whatever reason, I also query Categories in an unrelated query, the item-related query return with not proxies but actual hydrated Category instances, which I don't want.

```php
$this->categoryRepository->findBy(...);

...

$items = $this->itemRepository->findBy(...);
return $this->respond($items);
```

Here, $items[0]->category will have been populated by the framework by the time the execution reaches the return statement.

Is it possible to turn this behaviour off?

Comment: In your $items = example, I am pretty sure that $item is itself a proxy of item.  Accessing category is triggering the category loading.  Maybe you could confirm?  I think you will need another approach.

Comment: Have you tried calling `detach()` on your categories?

Comment: @Cerad, @msg, None of my objects are proxies. They are indeed the fully populated instances of my Entity classes, which are in this case, plain objects that inherit from no other class. For this reason I have no `detach()` method to call.

Comment: @msg, You're right, but it is a clumsy additional dependency I need to inject. :(
Thank you though.

Comment: When you retrieve the `categories` they [get cached](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork.html#how-doctrine-keeps-track-of-objects) in the `UnitOfWork` inside `EntityManager` and when you get the `items` the `categories` get hydrated from that cache. Unless they are detached. You can mess with the `UnitOfWork` but that's discouraged in the docs. Sorry to not be of more help

Comment: 1. Please paste full definitions of those fields/relations
2. Please check in "dev" env in Symfony profiler if there is additional SELECT query in this case:
"
Here, $items[0]->category will have been populated by the time it reaches return statement.
"
3. What is this doing "return $this->respond($items);" ? This is generating response in some API by any chance? If yes then you may consider using Serializer (for example https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html ). My point is that your response should not rely on objects in relations being proxies or not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `fetch` policy on a relationship to be `EXTRA_LAZY`, this will fetch the least amount of date on execution as possible. Per [the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html):

> With Doctrine 2.1 a feature called Extra Lazy is introduced for associations. Associations are marked as Lazy by default, which means the whole collection object for an association is populated the first time its accessed.

So in your `@ORM\ManyToOne()` annotation, add a parameter: `fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"` to the others.

Comment: The Category entity inside the Item entity is populated from memory because of the separate query I made in the controller, as the code snippet shows. If I only query the itemRepository and not the categoryRepository, even with the default LAZY strategy I get proxy objects, which would be fine for my case. However, sometimes I will have to query the other repositories and I don't want those queries to pollute my response with unnecessary data.